# DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

Already I had a problem in installing dlib but I solved it
Now another problem see -:

```
import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import dlib
  File "C:\Users\SAKTHIMICRO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dlib\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

#but I installed
#how to solve this?

I solved the first error by installing dlib specific
But now I had a new problem